# Sync local files automatically with minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

I have a Minikube with an application up and running within while the code is in my local.
My problem is, when I change anything in my local, that change is not reflected on my Minikube.

I can fix that with something like `docker cp local.txt container:local.txt` but if I do that I need to run that command everytime I change something in my local to have both environments synchronized.

How could I do something like setting a volume that matches my local with a container running in that Minikube, without manually executing any command?

Comment: I normally think of Kubernetes as a distributed clustered environment; why try to do live development inside that cluster?  Can you use non-container tools for day-to-day development, and only bring Minikube into the setup for final integration testing?

Comment: Sure I can @DavidMaze I just think it will be easier if my changes are automatically sent to the cluster